# Issue when issuing a SELECT query to a Hive table in Prestodb

Tags: hive, presto

I am able to connect to my Hive metastore, and doing a DESCRIBE:

```
DESCRIBE sample_07;
Query 20131113_025614_00005_af2fx, RUNNING, 1 node, 2 splits
   Column    |  Type   | Null | Partition Key 
-------------+---------+------+---------------
 code        | varchar | true | false         
 description | varchar | true | false         
 total_emp   | bigint  | true | false         
 salary      | bigint  | true | false         
(4 rows)
```

However, a SELECT does not work:

```
select * from sample_07;

2013-11-12T16:54:58.611-0800    DEBUG   query-scheduler-7   com.facebook.presto.execution.QueryStateMachine Query 20131113_005458_00004_af2fx is PLANNING
Query 20131113_005458_00004_af2fx failed: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.facebook.presto.hadoop.shaded.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: callId, status; Host Details : local host is: "sandbox.hortonworks.com/xx.xx.2.15"; destination host is: "sandbox.hortonworks.com":8020; 
presto:default> 2013-11-12T16:56:04.771-0800    ERROR   Stage-20131113_005458_00004_af2fx.1-219 com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution Error while starting stage 20131113_005458_00004_af2fx.1 ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveSplitIterable$HiveSplitQueue.computeNext(HiveSplitIterable.java:433) ~[na:na]
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveSplitIterable$HiveSplitQueue.computeNext(HiveSplitIterable.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
```

As you can tell, i am using Hortonworks' sandbox, so it may be that that's the issue? Or is it choking on the IP address ? Not completely sure i understand the problem.

cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message suggests that you are not running Presto against CDH4 but against Hortonworks Sandbox which I believe is Hadoop 2.2.0.  There are known incompatibilities at this point.  See this thread on the Presto Google Group for more information: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/lVLvMGP1sKE